# User profile Synchronization services missing in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, 2016

I am trying to import active directory in SharePoint 2016 but getting below error:

> The object UserProfileApplication Name=User Profile Service
>   Application was updated by another user.  Determine if these changes
>   will conflict, resolve any differences, and reapply the second change.

This error may also indicate a programming error caused by obtaining two copies of the same object in a single thread.

When I check "User profile Synchronization services" was missing in services in server? is this services is deprecated here in SP2016?
Can any one help here?

Answer (score 3):

One of the big change In SharePoint 2016 there is no UPA Sync services, rather we have two options.

- Active Directory Import( one way import from AD, here is guide(it is same for 2016)https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/
- User Profile Services with external identity manager( Microsoft Identity manager as sync engine.) Check this http://krossfarm.com/?p=145